# How i can save the char data directly to blob db?

Tags: c++, sqlite, blob

I need to save an wxBitmap to SQLite to a blob type without save to disk or on some media.
i have mybitmap as wxBitmap;
First must convert to wxImage and get data.
Ok until now i hope, but how i can  save the char data directly to blob db?
In sql must have

> update mytable SET blob_column='??????' WHERE id='1'

or something like that. How must construct query?

```
wxImage img=mybitmap.ConvertToImage();
unsigned char* data=img.GetData();
int datalength=img.GetWidth()*img.GetHeight()*3;
char *myBuffer = (char *)data;
```

The code bellow is for wxSQLite3 ...

```
    wxMemoryOutputStream mo;
img.SaveFile( mo, wxBITMAP_TYPE_PNG );

wxSQLite3Statement stmt = db.PrepareStatement("UPDATE mytable SET blob_column='?' WHERE id='1'");
stmt.Bind(0, (unsigned char *)mo.GetOutputStreamBuffer()->GetBufferStart(), mo.GetOutputStreamBuffer()->GetBufferSize());
stmt.ExecuteUpdate();
```

But how to translate for SQLite?

Comment: See the [documentation](http://utelle.github.io/wxsqlite3/docs/html/classwx_s_q_lite3_statement.html#ad17d5df6de00702c5e6acf7208652f30).

Comment: Obviously your application uses the wxWidgets library. Why don't you just use wxSQLite3 for accessing your SQLite database?

Comment: I have already use SQLite and must change all i have done.

Comment: In that case you may just take a look at the implementation of the corresponding methods of wxSQLite3. wxSQLite3 is a thin wrapper for SQLite, and quite often just a single SQLite function is called inside of the method implementation. For example, method Bind for binding a blob parameter just makes a call to the SQLite function sqlite3_bind_blob.